# PHP 5.5 not loading GetText properly?

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, gettext

I've run into a problem where gettext isn't working on Windows 7 with PHP 5.5.8 vc11 x86 and Apache 2.4. I have it enabled in php.ini and have GNU GetText installed as required. GetText also doesn't seem to be showing up when I invoke the phpinfo() function and is still causing a WSoD and throwing the error in my Apache logs of:

`[:error] [pid 4372:tid 784] [client ::1:60968] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function _() in <directory/file/etc.>`

`[:error] [pid 4372:tid 784] [client ::1:61771] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function bindtextdomain() in <directory/file/etc.>`

Yet, I know it's reading the correct php.ini file from the phpinfo() function's output and having PDO and OpenSSL's functionality working properly. I've been hunting for the last 2 hours for a solution and have come up dry.

The code I'm trying worked and continues to work flawlessly in my XAMPP installation with GetText enabled, so I do know it isn't the code I'm trying. *(And no, only the Apache 2.4 server is running. So, there's no conflict there.)*

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it, here's how:

The phpinfo() function started throwing junk into the Apache/logs/errors.txt as follows...

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\\php_gettext.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0`

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\\php_openssl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0`

`PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\\php_pdo_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0`

And phpinfo() was showing that while it was loading the dlls from php/ext, that the default path was C:\Windows. So, I changed my system's environmental variables as suggested at:

http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/510919-php-looking-php-ini-file-c-windows

Start -> (Right Click) My Computer -> Properties -> Advanced Tab -> Environmental Variables Button

Under "System Variables" you'll find the Variable of "Path". You need to add the the path to your php.ini file in there after the existing data, for example: `;c:\php` *(You need the `;` to separate from the previous value.)*

After changing that value, you need to reboot Windows so the added environmental variable takes effect and can hook into Apache/PHP at start-up.

Comment: I'm just silly and didn't install PHP properly because I've been spoiled by *AMPs and Linux. Better/Official documentation of changing the path for the PHP install can be found here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath